# How to open div over sibling div with Jquery and CSS

Tags: html, jquery, css

Hello I'm trying to make a more friendly UI for user when they click on a point on a map. I want the popup button to open a popup vertically (Bottom to Top) from the bottom of the div map. This is on a mobile app and there is not much room to work with. So I've seen a few apps open up the pop-up info from the bottom of the map and cover 1/3 of the map with the pop-up info. [image]

I created a JSfiddle here https://jsfiddle.net/5kdryesz/

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.5.1/dist/leaflet.css" integrity="sha512-xwE/Az9zrjBIphAcBb3F6JVqxf46+CDLwfLMHloNu6KEQCAWi6HcDUbeOfBIptF7tcCzusKFjFw2yuvEpDL9wQ==" crossorigin="" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">


  <!-- Bootstrap core JS-->
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/3590d6dbc0.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <!-- Jquery JS-->
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B4gt1jrGC7Jh4AgTPSdUtOBvfO8shuf57BaghqFfPlYxofvL8/KUEfYiJOMMV+rV" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js" integrity="sha256-VazP97ZCwtekAsvgPBSUwPFKdrwD3unUfSGVYrahUqU=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <style>
    #map {
      height: 700px;
      width: 500px;
      background-color: rgb(52, 58, 64);
    }
    
    .popup {
      display: none;
      background-color: blueviolet;
      width: 500px;
    }
  </style>

</head>

<body>
  <div> Testing </div>
  <button id='popupbtn'> popup</button>
  <div class='container'>
    <div id='map'></div>
    <div id='popupdiv' class='popup'> Info This needs to go over Map div
      <br>phone: 324234
      <br>email: asdfsa@ssdf.sdf</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    testing and thinds
  </div>
</body>
<script>
  var map = L.map('map').setView([51.505, -0.09], 13);

  L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
  }).addTo(map);

  L.marker([51.5, -0.09]).addTo(map)
    .bindPopup('A pretty CSS3 popup.<br> Easily customizable.')


  $("#popupbtn").click(function() {
    $("#popupdiv").show("slide", {
      direction: "down"
    }, 600);

  })
</script>

</html>
```

I'm having issues understanding the position css property. I've tried absolute but just couldn't figured it out and I'm curious if absolute will work with all different sizes of phones.  Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this may help you.

If you use position:absolute then you should have position relative to its parent div.

google map (.leaflet-bottom) has z-index value 1000 so put our popup on map we should have higher z-index value of popup hence i have put z-index value 1001 to our popup.

```js
var map = L.map('map').setView([51.505, -0.09], 13);

L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
}).addTo(map);

L.marker([51.5, -0.09]).addTo(map)
    .bindPopup('A pretty CSS3 popup.<br> Easily customizable.')


$("#popupbtn").click(function(){
    $("#popupdiv").show("slide", { direction: "down" }, 600);

})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.5.1/dist/leaflet.css" integrity="sha512-xwE/Az9zrjBIphAcBb3F6JVqxf46+CDLwfLMHloNu6KEQCAWi6HcDUbeOfBIptF7tcCzusKFjFw2yuvEpDL9wQ==" crossorigin=""/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- Bootstrap core JS-->
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/3590d6dbc0.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <!-- Jquery JS-->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script> 
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B4gt1jrGC7Jh4AgTPSdUtOBvfO8shuf57BaghqFfPlYxofvL8/KUEfYiJOMMV+rV" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js" integrity="sha256-VazP97ZCwtekAsvgPBSUwPFKdrwD3unUfSGVYrahUqU=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <style>

        #map {
        height: 500px;
        width: 300px;
        background-color: rgb(52, 58, 64);
        }

        .popup{
            display: none;
            background-color: blueviolet;
            width: 300px;
            position:absolute;
            bottom:0;
            z-index:1001;
        }
        .container{
          position:relative;
        }

    </style>

</head>
<body>
    <div> Testing </div>
    <button id = 'popupbtn'> popup</button>
    <div class = 'container'>
        <div id= 'map'></div>
        <div id = 'popupdiv' class = 'popup'> Info  This needs to go over Map div 
            <br>phone: 324234
            <br>email: asdfsa@ssdf.sdf</div>
    </div>
    <div>
        testing and thinds
    </div>
</body>
<script>


</script>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks that worked. So ywah you need absolute for the positioning . the bottom : 0 makes it so it starts at the bottom and the z-index of 1001. i was putting 1000 and it was not going over top. I see thank you so much !

Answer (score 0):

I assume this is what you need. I used z-index to put the pop-up on top of the map and fixed positioning to put the pop-up at the bottom.

The height of the pop-up will be the same on each device: 30% of the screen. The with is fixed because the width of the map is fixed and therefore also the pop-up.

If the pop-up needs to be 30% of the height of the map, it can be an absolute value.

```js
var map = L.map('map').setView([51.505, -0.09], 13);

L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
  attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
}).addTo(map);

L.marker([51.5, -0.09]).addTo(map)
  .bindPopup('A pretty CSS3 popup.<br> Easily customizable.')


$("#popupbtn").click(function() {
  $("#popupdiv").show("slide", {
    direction: "down"
  }, 600);

})
```

```css
#map {
  height: 700px;
  width: 500px;
  background-color: rgb(52, 58, 64);
  position: relative;
  z-index: 10;
}

.popup {
  display: none;
  background-color: blueviolet;
  width: 500px;
  height: 30vw;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 20;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.5.1/dist/leaflet.css" integrity="sha512-xwE/Az9zrjBIphAcBb3F6JVqxf46+CDLwfLMHloNu6KEQCAWi6HcDUbeOfBIptF7tcCzusKFjFw2yuvEpDL9wQ==" crossorigin="" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/3590d6dbc0.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B4gt1jrGC7Jh4AgTPSdUtOBvfO8shuf57BaghqFfPlYxofvL8/KUEfYiJOMMV+rV" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js" integrity="sha256-VazP97ZCwtekAsvgPBSUwPFKdrwD3unUfSGVYrahUqU=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div> Testing </div>
<button id='popupbtn'> popup</button>
<div class='container'>
  <div id='map'></div>
  <div id='popupdiv' class='popup'> Info This needs to go over Map div
    <br>phone: 324234
    <br>email: asdfsa@ssdf.sdf</div>
</div>
<div>
  testing and thinds
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Gerard I think the above comment from Prakash works well. appreciate the help!